# Debugging a Policykit error

Tags: policykit

I am getting the following error when attempting to access the /mnt/data directory from the desktop.

> GDBus.error:org.freedesktop.Policykit1.Error.Failed:Unix process subject does not have uid set

The directory is managed by LVM with the mount path location defined in /etc/fstab and established at boot. Running `mount | grep /mnt` outputs

> /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-lvdata on /mnt/data type ext4 (rw,relatime)

The mount is visible in Gnome Files after logging into the Ubuntu desktop with my normal credentials. Upon selecting the Data directory for the first time from Files app it brings up a password dialogue box where I have to reenter my login password.

Strangely I can access the directory from a console.

I am now running Ubuntu desktop 21.10. I have viewed the logs with `journalctl -f -u polkit.service` but see nothing there that makes any sense.

I have tried resetting things by running `sudo chown shaun:shaun -R /mnt/data` but no luck.

Any ideas on how to track down the cause of the problem would be much appreciated.

I have included a screenshot of the error dialogue [Gnome Desktop Error Dialogue Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fv2n.png)

Comment: I am using the Gnome Files application in a standard desktop user login session.

Comment: There is an interesting article on why Polkit exists and the way it works here https://smcv.pseudorandom.co.uk/2015/why_polkit/

Comment: It would appear a few people over in the Arch Linux forums have been able to identify the cause of the error is related to an update to the gnome virtual file system gvfs...https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=264716 https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=264716